# android webview onpagefinished called twice but shouldOverrideUrlLoading only called once

Tags: android, webview

I load url in android webview found that onpagefinished() called twice but shouldOverrideUrlLoading only been called once.

The url is connect to online payment after first loaded the url has been added with the param like '#!cardIndex?r=0.8913584462445969' then I can't go back to the previous page.

What has happened and how could I solve this problem.

```
@Override
public void onPageFinished(String url) {
    mNavView.setWebTitle();
    if (!mIsLoadFailed) {
        mLastLoadSuccessIndex = getCurrentWebHistoryItemIndex();
    if(url.contains("95516")&&url.contains("?r=")){
            mLastLoadSuccessIndex = mLastLoadSuccessIndex-2 ;  
            VLog.e(TAG,mLastLoadSuccessIndex+"---------"+url);
      }
    }}

   private class HtmlWebClient extends WebViewClient {

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

        VLog.d(TAG, "shouldOverrideUrlLoading, url = " + url);

        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(url)) {
            return true;
        }

        if (url.startsWith("mailto:")) { //屏蔽邮箱
            return true;
        }
```

Comment: share some code please

Comment: i have added code to my question